# Django: LoginView redirects me to accounts/profile instead of the previous page

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

My page has a navigation bar that is visible on all pages. There is a "Sign In/Sign Up" button. After signing in I would like to redirect the user to the previous page.

Example:

I'm currently looking to buy vinyl at http://127.0.0.1:8000/vinyls/. I press "Sign In" and I type my credentials. After clicking the Submit button, I would like to get back to /vinyls/. The same goes for /record_labels/, /events/ etc.

I tried using `<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">` in my sign-in template but I get redirected to /accounts/profile. Then I tried using `<a id="nav-a" href="{% url 'sign in' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Sign Up/Sign In</a>` but I'm redirected to /accounts/profile.

This is my SignInView:

```py
class SignInView(auth_views.LoginView):
    template_name = 'sign-in.html'
```

This is my sign-in.html:

```html
<h1>Sign in</h1>
<form method="post" action="{% url 'sign in' %}">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
    <p>
        <button type="submit">Sign in</button>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </p>
    <p>Not a member? <a href="{% url 'sign up' %}">Sign up now</a></p>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you redirect your user to the login page? Is `next` actually  populated?

Comment: When I use `<a id="nav-a" href="{% url 'sign in' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Sign Up/Sign In</a>` the URL changes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/sign-in/?next=/vinyls/ but when I click submit it redirects me to the default URL for the LoginView

Comment: I mean from your other pages like `/vinyls/`, etc. how are you redirecting the user to the login page? Are you using the `login_required` decorator or the `LoginRequiredMixin`?

Comment: There is a button "Sign In/Sign Up" on the navigation bar.

Comment: Oh, I don't know what happened but now I'm redirected to the previous page. I didn't touch anything. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '[your-redirect url]'
```

to the `settings.py` file in your project should solve it.

See [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication#:%7E:text=If%20you%20log%20in%20using,may%20not%20be%20the%20case.).